# Get files from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, ssis

I have SharePoint Online in my environment, where users upload files (txt, xls, etc.) to document libraries.

How can I implement the following steps:

1) automatically detect that a new file was uploaded, get library name and file name;

2) call SSIS package, deployed to Integration Services catalog on server X, to copy file to local disk on server X for any further processing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create MS Flow and high level logic of flow would be below.

- Flow trigger point - when file is created
- Use Get the file action to get file
- Use Create file action to create a file in some system.

It is little tricky and you can use below links for reference.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/HTTP-get-download-file/td-p/49568

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2018/10/14/microsoft-flow-copy-files-from-sharepoint-to-a-local-pc/